# How to configure the jflow correctly in my juniper router?

Tags: juniper, netflow

I configured the jFlow sampling in Juniper MX480:

[image]

but in my receive data server, there is no data received:

[image]

and when I use Paessler Netflow Tester test it, there cannot use `14.224.224.253`:

[image]

Whether should I stop some processes then I can use it to receive data?

and when I use `Any` IP with 50001 port,  there get nothing data received.

[image]

I use wireshark capture the packages, do not get the udp:50001  data:

[image]

Is there any problem with the MX480's jflow configuration?

---

When I `show chassis hardware`:

```
admin@MX-RE0> show chassis hardware 
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                JN1268969AFB      MX480
Midplane         REV 46   750-047862   ACRK8432          Enhanced MX480 Midplane
FPM Board        REV 04   760-059208   CAKN5259          Front Panel Display
PEM 0            Rev 01   740-063046   QCS1803U0LR       PS 1.4-2.52kW; 90-264V AC in
PEM 1            Rev 01   740-063046   QCS1803U0WF       PS 1.4-2.52kW; 90-264V AC in
PEM 2            Rev 01   740-063046   QCS1803U0NS       PS 1.4-2.52kW; 90-264V AC in
PEM 3            Rev 01   740-063046   QCS1803U0VE       PS 1.4-2.52kW; 90-264V AC in
Routing Engine 0 REV 05   740-051822   9016248981        RE-S-1800x4
Routing Engine 1 REV 05   740-051822   9016235698        RE-S-1800x4
CB 0             REV 09   750-062572   CAKR2658          Enhanced MX SCB 2
CB 1             REV 09   750-062572   CADK1607          Enhanced MX SCB 2
FPC 0            REV 38   750-037358   CABX1478          MPC4E 3D 32XGE
  CPU            REV 10   711-035209   CACP5100          HMPC PMB 2G 
  PIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           8X10GE SFPP
    Xcvr 0       REV 01   740-021309   JU180630051       SFP+-10G-LR
  PIC 1                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           8X10GE SFPP
    Xcvr 0       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825026       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 1       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825020       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 2       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825027       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 3       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825019       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 4       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825024       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 5       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825021       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 6       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825023       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 7       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825022       SFP+-10G-SR
  PIC 2                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           8X10GE SFPP
  PIC 3                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           8X10GE SFPP
FPC 1            REV 38   750-037358   CABX1481          MPC4E 3D 32XGE
  CPU            REV 10   711-035209   CACA0481          HMPC PMB 2G 
  PIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           8X10GE SFPP
  PIC 1                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           8X10GE SFPP
    Xcvr 0       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825017       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 1       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825018       UNSUPPORTED
    Xcvr 2       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825013       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 3       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825015       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 4       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825012       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 5       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825014       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 6       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825011       SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 7       REV 01   740-021308   JU180825016       SFP+-10G-SR
  PIC 2                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           8X10GE SFPP
  PIC 3                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           8X10GE SFPP
FPC 3            REV 46   750-056519   CALM0754          MPC7E 3D MRATE-12xQSFPP-XGE-XLGE-CGE
  CPU            REV 21   750-057177   CALK1181          SMPC PMB
  PIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           MRATE-6xQSFPP-XGE-XLGE-CGE
    Xcvr 2       REV 01   740-058732   QH94580045        QSFP-100GBASE-LR4
    Xcvr 5       REV 01   740-061412   1NUQ513901P       QSFP-100G-CWDM4
  PIC 1                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           MRATE-6xQSFPP-XGE-XLGE-CGE
    Xcvr 2       REV 01   740-061409   1GCQA2280QA       QSFP-100GBASE-LR4
    Xcvr 5       REV 01   740-061412   1NUQ513901U       QSFP-100G-CWDM4
Fan Tray                                                 Enhanced Left Fan Tray

{master}
```

I do not find any MPC there.

and there shows nothing for checking `accounting`:

```
admin@MX-RE0> show services accounting status 

{master}
admin@MX-RE0> show services accounting flow 

{master}
```

Comment: What does `show services accounting flow` show you?  Also, do you have any DPCs or does your MX only have MPCs installed?

Comment: See my updated post, and I hear about `version 5 ` do not need any MPC.

Comment: One more question, is there a reason you're doing version 5?  All of this processing will be done on the routing engine and depending on your sampling interval/run rate, put additional strain on it.  Your other option is v9 or v10 (IPFIX) which is done directly on the cards themselves.  I'll provide the answer you're looking for, I just wanted to make sure you were aware.